# How to protect a personal server on the cloud?

Tags: debian, security

I have setup a personal Debian 8 server on the cloud. Have installed a desktop, vnc and dropbox to link some existing files.

How do I protect my server, among other things, from someone accessing my dropbox?

Comment: I hope you realize that "the cloud" is really nothing more than "someone else's computer(s)".  If they want to, whoever owns the computer(s) you're using can see everything you're doing on *their* computer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. expose to internet the minimum services not using default ports
2. strong passwords
3. fail2ban
4. keep update the sw to get security fixes

Comment: hey, downvote without any clue ... big help to improve !